# Strange problem of ggplot when I try to plot a rectangle

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

# to plot a rectangle
x = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
y = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
ggplot(NULL, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

[result, why the upper line is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANYaF.png)

```
x = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0) + rnorm(5, 0, 1)*0.01
y = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0) + rnorm(5, 0, 1)*0.01
ggplot(NULL, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

[result, why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRUej.png)

Comment: A line assumes everything is ordered along the x-axis. You might instead be looking for `geom_path()` which leaves the ordering as-is.

Comment: Thanks, ~~~~~~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the top line is missing is that `geom_line` sorts the co-ordinates according to their position on the x axis before plotting them. It does not plot points in the order in which they appear in the vector.

It is a `geom_path` that allows arbitrary ordering of x and y values and would produce the lines you want:

```r
x = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
y = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
ggplot(NULL, aes(x, y)) + geom_path()
```

[image]

In a sense, a `geom_line` is just a `geom_path` where the points have been ordered by ascending x value. We can replicate the behaviour of `geom_line` by ordering manually:

```r
ggplot(NULL, aes(x[order(x)], y[order(x)])) + geom_path()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try `geom_rect`

```
df <- data.frame(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax=1)
ggplot(df, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)) + 
  geom_rect(fill=NA, color =1)
```

then you can do some tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
map(rnorm(5, 0, 1)*0.01, function(x) df*x) %>% 
   bind_rows() %>% 
   rownames_to_column() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, color = rowname )) + 
   geom_rect(fill=NA) + 
   coord_fixed()
```

[image]